# Ошибка в qiwi api

Tags: node.js, qiwi

node js qiwi api. все работало но в определенный момент начал выдавать ошибку и выключать приложение. Бот телеграмм

```js
2019-09-27T19:09:35.833715+00:00 app[app.1]: /app/node_modules/node-qiwi-api/node-qiwi-api.js:75
2019-09-27T19:09:35.833730+00:00 app[app.1]:                 url: this.apiUri + 'payment-history/v1/persons/' + data.authInfo.personId + '/payments',
2019-09-27T19:09:35.833731+00:00 app[app.1]:                                                                                  ^
2019-09-27T19:09:35.833732+00:00 app[app.1]: 
2019-09-27T19:09:35.833733+00:00 app[app.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'personId' of undefined
2019-09-27T19:09:35.833738+00:00 app[app.1]:     at getAccountInfo (/app/node_modules/node-qiwi-api/node-qiwi-api.js:75:82)
2019-09-27T19:09:35.833739+00:00 app[app.1]:     at Request.request.get [as _callback] (/app/node_modules/node-qiwi-api/node-qiwi-api.js:47:13)
2019-09-27T19:09:35.833740+00:00 app[app.1]:     at Request.self.callback (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)
2019-09-27T19:09:35.833744+00:00 app[app.1]:     at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
2019-09-27T19:09:35.833745+00:00 app[app.1]:     at Request.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1171:10)
2019-09-27T19:09:35.833746+00:00 app[app.1]:     at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
2019-09-27T19:09:35.833747+00:00 app[app.1]:     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1091:12)
2019-09-27T19:09:35.833748+00:00 app[app.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
2019-09-27T19:09:35.833749+00:00 app[app.1]:     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
2019-09-27T19:09:35.833750+00:00 app[app.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
2019-09-27T19:09:35.833751+00:00 app[app.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Не могу понять. Помогите пожалуйста Сверху ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что метод getOperationHistory вызывает метод getAccountInfo, для получения номера кошелька. Это сделано для того, чтобы получать номер автоматически по токену внутри метода. В вашем случае, в результате вызова getAccountInfo authInfo - undefined.
Пожалуйста, проверьте, что возвращает метод getAccountInfo.